# Spring Security in Jsp Servlets

Tags: jsp, spring-security, servlet-filters

Can Spring Security be implemented on basic JSP and Servlets(non-maven projects) login and logout process.Is there any other way around to stop the user from going to the profile page without loging in by pressing back button.If not please tell me how to implement Spring Security in basic JSP and Servlet login and logout page.

Comment: Yes, Spring Security can do this.

Comment: can u give an example or link for the same?